# Underscores in literals are not supported at this language level

Tags: java, java-7, literals

I got this error when creating a final double using underscores to make the double more readable. It was declared in a `run()` method.

```
public void run() {        
    final double nanoSeconds = 1_000_000_000.0 / 60.0;    
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.

Comment: It looks like it's unsupported with older versions of java.

Comment: This is a Java 7 feature: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

Comment: What build tool are you using? Maven?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `IntelliJ IDEA` you have to change `Project language level` in project settings to `7.0` level:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: I'm not using Maven, and I'm using JRE 7. Thanks, Andremoniy. It worked :)

Comment: @MichaelJarvis you are welcome. The best "thanks" will be vote-up :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes..you need to change the default language level settings if you are using and IDE. For IntelliJ users it is under File --> Project Structure --> Projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found with my project that had modules, I had to do this in the modules settings as well.

[image: Modules project settings]