# Error: "binary literals are not supported at this language level "

Tags: java, intellij-idea, literals

I am using JDK 1.7 and getting the error "binary literals are not supported at this language level" when I attempt to use expressions such as:

```
 int x = 0b000001;
```

I thought binary literals were supported by 1.7?

Comment: You might have JDK 1.7, but your IDE is set to target level 1.6.

Comment: possible duplicate [Underscores in literals are not supported at this language level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986346/underscores-in-literals-are-not-supported-at-this-language-level)

Comment: @Reimeus this is about binary literals, not underscores

Comment: The solution is the same most probably.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, it appears that even though you might be using a particular JDK, it can "target" features of a previous version, thanks for the tip

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the solution may be same, but the QUESTION is different

Comment: Ah yes, Stack Overflow assumes that questions:answers is one:many.  But many:many might be a better model.  In this case, both questions are "I'm trying to use a Java 7 feature in my Java 7 environment, but it says my language level is wrong"; but it's useful to allow both questions to exist, so that people can search for "binary literals" or for "underscores in literals".

Comment: All questions are duplicates to the answer "42".

Comment: Kind of amazing this question has 1000 views and only 1 vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution in Intellij 13.2 and similar: Select menu choice `File/Project Structure`. The following dialog appears:

[image]

Set **Project language level** to be what is needed (7.0 for binary literals).